# Передача потока в конструктор другого потока

Tags: java

Что позволяет сделать `Runnable target` в конструкторе `public Thread(Runnable target, String name)`?

Допустим, у нас есть:

```
public static class TestedThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestedThread commonThread = new TestedThread();

    Thread threadA = new Thread(commonThread, "Нить 1");
    Thread threadB = new Thread(commonThread, "Нить 2");

    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
}
```

Какой смысл передавать поток в конструктор другого потока?

Comment: `Runnable` это же не поток, а интерфейс из одной функции. И вы можете свои классы создавать реализуя интерфейс `Runnable`. Пример таких классов: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html в `All Known Implementing Classes:`

Comment: Считайте что `Runnable` - это такое соглашение. Т.е. если вы хотите, чтобы ваш класс был запущен в отдельном потоке - он должен реализовывать интерфейс `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор `Thread` принимает объект типа `Runnable`. Передать туда объект `Thread` можно лишь потому, что `Thread implements Runnable`

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String)) описывает что происходит с переданным объектом (`target`):

> target - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started. If null, this thread's run method is invoked.

То есть если передан не `null`, то при запуске потока будет вызван метод `run` переданного объекта

Изменённый пример из вопроса:

```
private static class ThreadA extends Thread
{
    public ThreadA(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("ThreadA.run runs in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

private static class ThreadB extends Thread
{
    public ThreadB(Runnable target, String name)
    {
        super(target, name);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Thread threadA = new ThreadA("Thread1");
    Thread threadB = new ThreadB(threadA, "Thread2");
    threadB.start();
}
```

Вывод:

> ThreadA.run runs in thread Thread2

---

Если переопределить метод `run` в `ThreadB` и не вызывать в нём `target`:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("ThreadB.run runs in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

то смысла в передаче `target` не будет:

> ThreadB.run runs in thread Thread2